# Get position of objects using kinect and C#

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine, kinect, emgucv

I got a kinect mount in the ceiling pointing down to a table (that is roughly 2 to 3 meters of the kinect) and my objective is using the kinect depth stream, locate the objects and get their position to late send to unity. So for that i am using c sharp and opencv (emgu wrapper), i first use canny to get the edges and then use BoundingRect to create a box around the object.

The result is the as follows:

[image]

Original:

[image]

As you can see the stationary objects are no problem but the box around the hands (the first was a flyer on it) is to big and sometimes is even worse. Is there any other way (using opencv ) of getting the positions of the objects?

The objective is then to send the position and dimension (of the object) to unity (trough tcp/ip), so preferably the shapes have to squares or rectangles to easy manipulation on unity.

The code I have so far is:

```
    Image<Bgr, Byte> grayImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("C:\\Users\\Pedro\\Desktop\\imgRva\\KinectSnapshot-03-48-01.png");
    Image<Gray, Byte> gray = grayImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
    CvInvoke.cvShowImage("texto", gray);
    CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(0);
    Image<Gray, Byte> bin = gray.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(40), new Gray(255));
    Image<Gray, Byte> cannyEdges = bin.Canny(300, 300);
    CvInvoke.cvShowImage("texto", cannyEdges);
    CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(0);

    Image<Gray, Byte> canny = new Image<Gray, byte>(cannyEdges.Size);
    using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())

        for (Contour<Point> contours = cannyEdges.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
        {
            CvInvoke.cvDrawContours(canny, contours, new MCvScalar(255), new MCvScalar(255), -1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED, new Point(0, 0));
        }

    using (MemStorage store = new MemStorage())
        for (Contour<Point> contours1 = cannyEdges.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE, store); contours1 != null; contours1 = contours1.HNext)
        {
            Rectangle r = CvInvoke.cvBoundingRect(contours1, 1);
            canny.Draw(r, new Gray(255), 1);
            Debug.WriteLine(r.Location + " x " + r.Width + " y " + r.Height);
        }
    CvInvoke.cvShowImage("texto", canny);
    CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(0);
```

Ty

Comment: *but the box around the hands is to big*, doesn't look too big to me. Not sure how big you think it should be.

Comment: The objective is to have interaction with objects in a game in unity and ifyou look for example at the left hand the box is too big

Comment: How is the box to big? How could it be smaller and still enclose the whole hand? Or is the idea that it shouldn't enclose the whole hand? But in that case, since I assume your intention is to do some kind of collision detection, your detection is going to be bad, missing the tips of fingers for example.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what u mean. The Problem is, that OpenCv recognizes your hand and the flyer as one object. So the box around that one object is correct.

I'm not an Expert on OpenCv and i dont know how openCv recognizes object.

But in your case it should be possible to use the depthinformatioen to filter your hand off.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).